# Survey article on quasitoric manifolds

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I am looking for a good overview on quasitoric manifolds. I have read *Toric Topology* by Buchstaber and Panov which was good but I was wondering if there is something that has more. Something like a (almost) complete history of the subject. Does someone know of such a source?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The notion of quasitoric manifold was introduced by Davis and Januszkiewicz in the paper "Convex polytopes, Coxeter orbifolds and torus actions" in Duke Math. J. 62 (1991). The book "Toric Topology" by Buchstaber and Panov (2015) contains a lot of important results on quasitoric manifolds already. But still there are some other interesting results on this topic scattered in papers published by different authors. Since these papers all quote Davis-Januszkiewicz's original paper, I would recommend one to search MathSciNet.

Comment: The question was not about the origin of the subject, but about providing a review article, possibly containing the history of its development.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mathoverflow.net/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/157060)